# How to bring a drone through a country that does not allow them?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, drones

You travel several countries with one backpack. Some of them restrict drones, some do not. You are NOT going to fly in the country where drones are illegal, but you want to take it with you to another country and fly there, where drones are legal.
Will it help to temporarily disassemble the drone, propellers, maybe legs, for the custom check?

Comment: If this is about *smuggling*, it is about asking us how to break the law. If not, the question is badly written. Voting to close.

Comment: Is possession of drones illegal in any of the countries in question, or only operating them?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't support illegal activities.

Comment: A better phrased question would be "How can I legally bring a drone into country X". Without specifying the country, I don't see a general way in which this can be answered. Now it's like: how can I bring cocaine into a country without border security noticing.

Comment: For some countries I see drones are confiscated at customs, while other countries give temporary import permits

Comment: The term that you are looking for is called **Customs Transit**. Mostly done in a form of a **Customs Seal** applied in the country of origin and checked by the customs of the country in transit during transport to a country where it is allowed. Not common  for individual travel in most cases, but a **legal** method to transport an object through a third country in transit. It would probably be better to ship the drone using this method.

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes, that's a nice point, but as you said, it's quite complicated once we speak about solo backpacker. My idea is to dissasemble the drone, but that's just a teory. I'll be happy to know real world experiences.

* for the comments above, please read with understanding, nobody doing anything ilegal. Misleading title it's my fault. Thank's for correction!

Comment: @o.m. This question should not be closed, since a **legal** method is being asked for. Since such a method not only exists but is also an everyday method used by customs and a legitimate answer can be given. Starting 2021 all goods transports from or to Ireland through the United Kingdom will use such methods.

Comment: @MarkJohnson, I answered before the edit.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan : Yep, that's the valid question to ask.

Comment: @o.m. Sorry, didn't see that. Yes, with that wording is understandable, but has now been changed.

Comment: @JZK Others have already asked which country you are asking about, but you do not specify that. It probably all boils down to what Patricia asked: Is *posession* or *operating* the drone illegal? There may also be regulations relevant for the radio transmitter in the remote control unit, even in countries where a drone per se is legal to posess.

Answer (score 23):

The term that you are looking for is called **[Customs Transit](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2018/1258/schedule/1/part/2/made)**. Mostly done in a form of a **[Customs Seal](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notice-205-official-customs-seals-and-trader-sealing/notice-205-official-customs-seals-and-trader-sealing)** applied in the country of origin and checked by the customs of the country in transit during transport to a country where it is allowed and where it is then *unsealed*.

Not common for individual travel in most cases, but a legal method to transport an object through a third country in transit.

It would probably be better to ship the drone using this method with a [Poste restante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante) service as address.

Such methods are an everyday affair for transport firms. Many are authorized by customs authorities to seal such containers (called: **Trader sealing**).

Precondition is, of course, that the object is allowed for transport in the *sending* and *receiving* countries and not on an absolute forbidden list of the country of transit.

Starting 2021 all goods transports from or to Ireland through the United Kingdom will use such methods.

---

**Sources**:

- [Official customs seals and trader sealing (Notice 205) - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/notice-205-official-customs-seals-and-trader-sealing/notice-205-official-customs-seals-and-trader-sealing)
- [The Customs Transit Procedures (EU Exit) Regulations 2018](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2018/1258/schedule/1/part/2/made)
- [Poste restante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante)

Comment: This procedure is not only uncommon for individual travel (as you point out yourself in a comment), but usually plain impossible. It is rather used for large-scale commercial freight transport through intermediate countries and not at all appicable for a single item in a tourist's luggage. From the UK laws you are linking to: The applicant must both be established in the UK and regularly use the transit procedure to get an authorization. This is clearly not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo [City Sprint, Royal Mail, Amazon Logistics, Parcelforce, Hermes, DHL, Fedex, UPS and DPD](https://www.which.co.uk/reviews/best-and-worst-shops/article/best-and-worst-delivery-companies-adzRt3m47ABD) are only a few of the delivery services available in the UK which will use a **Customs Seal** when needed. So this **might not be clear to you** that this answers the *How to bring a drone through a country that does not allow them?* , but please do not assume is is not clear to others, many of whom often use such services.

Comment: I have no idea why you think delivery service's use of custom seals is in any way relevant to the question. It is also generally not possible if you are travelling from country A, via B to C to mail arbitrary tings from A to C to prevent customs issues in country B. It is not obvious that you have an adress in C, to which you can mail anything, delivery times may prevent such a solution and for more expensive items like a drone, you would probably have to pay import duties in country C. Duty excemption for travel luggage usually only apply if you carry the luggage when entering the country.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Because the answer gives a legal solution to get the drone to country C, avoiding problems in country B and that is what the OP is asking for: **how** it can be done. [Poste restante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante) services are also easily obtainable. Such methods have been practiced for centuries. Long before Credit Cards and eMails were common place, *American Express* was best known for it's Traveler Checks and Poste restante services for travellers, so all of this is nothing new.

Comment: I know very well what poste restante is, namely an outdated mean to reach travellers. Poste restante services are therefore in many countries discontinued and not at all readily available anymore, since you now instead can make a call or send an e-mail instead. Where poste restante services are still offered, they are often limited to letters and/or domestic parcels and kept for a short period, like a week. You can not in general expect that you can use poste restante to mail yourself luggage when you are travelling.

Comment: Based on the wiki article (and personal experience) it is a) not obsolete, since it still on offer ; b) packages are possible in many countries. Kindly supply sources for your contradicting *claims*.

Comment: well, althought the correct answer was givern, it doesn't solve my(and many other's) situation. You speak about UK, I speak about Uzbekistan, Iran, Turkmenistan and other countries where half of regular mail's get lost, not mentioning sensitive and expensive electronics...so, once more, I consider your answer correct, but real world needs real solutions. For now, I stick with dissasembling, as I'm electronic engineer. Still, I'll be happy to find better solution without screwdriver. Many backpackers will thank

Comment: @JZK Real solutions also need real data. You only now state which countries are indended. You can't expect an answer using those countries if you failed to meantioned them. The UK was used as a sample due solely on the English language text that existed for the explanation of the terminology. Be it as it may, I don't think there is a doable solution for a individual traveler. A drone well **not** be considered a essential personal item. The value may exceed the duty free amount allowed. The nearest you will get will be the regulations for *sport equipment* which is temporary imported.

Comment: @MarkJohnson There are several for this case relevant restrictions mentioned in the Wikipedia article you are linking to. But for a specific example: In Germany, poste restante is only possible for letters (no parcels/packets), only available at certain post offices and letters are only kept for 7 days. They offer a similar service for parcels, but it is only available to registered recipients, who are resident in Germany (more similar to having a post box than poste restante).and can not be used for international parcels if customs clearance is required.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo And the same article states that for Ireland poste restante can be used for anyone that doesn't have an address in that town or city and for Italy it can be used for letters and packages. So your point is, when looking at the **whole** picture (and not cherry picking)  is?

Comment: Who is cherry picking? First of all, I listed several other reasons why mailing stuff along the way is usually not a good solution when travelling. You started cherry picking by only objecting one of the several reasons I mentioned. You have now found one country, namely Ireland, which BTW is utterly irrelevant for the question, since noone is going to Ireland, and show that poste restante is available there without solving the other issues. Try to mail a drone e.g. from Norway to Ireland and you would in Ireland have to pay import duties (customs and VAT) for the drone's value.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo You are, by selecting a post system where it not possible to use poste restante in **every** office to confirm your claim that it is *obsolete*. But the reality is: [Thanks to its membership in the Universal Postal Union, the Post enables the storage of letters and parcels from abroad.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postlagernd#Postlagernd_in_Deutschland). My citing of Ireland **and Italy** was only to show that your claim is false, since all members of the *Universal Postal Union* are required to offer this service. Ypour claims are not based on knowledge.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You are not understanding what you are linking to. The text in the German Wikipedia article is incomplete, but you can find the entire story if you simply follow the reference links to the DHL product description. Receiving parcels at the post office is the service I already wrote about several comments further up. It is only available for registered customers and you must be resident in Germany to register. It is not available for international parcels, which require customs clearance.

Comment: You asked for sources of my claim and I mentioned one example. It is not room for a detailed description of poste restante services for 200 countries in a 600 character SE comment and it is not my job to do trivial research for you. Even OP has now told you that this is not a practical solution to his problem.

Comment: I don't think that the whole concept with POST it's acceptable. I propose to keep topic around keeping your drone with you, but have it either, sealed, or dissasembled, or anything else. If for nothing more, than for the sake of flexibiity